# jQuery toggle menu with slide and Easing

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make a menu that has a moving display.

It seems there are many ways, but I can't find a solution that fit these requirements :

- possibility to do a "Easing"
- slide from the left then right on a click

For now I have this and the toggle works :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu").click(function(){
        $("#nav1").toggle("slide");
    });
});
```

Comment: Place the menu outside of the screen and animate its "left" property value. See http://api.jquery.com/animate/ for details, there are some suitable examples.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'moving display' you mean a recurring animation, **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/zs70gs78/1/)** is a very dirty way to achieve it without the use of external plugins. Also, it won't start the animation inmediately.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.box').delay(2000).animate({"margin-left": "100px"})
                 .delay(2000).animate({"margin-left": "20px"});
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toggleClass` feature by JQuery.

JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
$('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
// create menu variables
var slideoutMenu = $('.slideout-menu');
var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.slideout-menu').width();
// toggle open class
slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");
// slide menu
if (slideoutMenu.hasClass("open")) {
slideoutMenu.animate({
left: "0px"
}); 
} else {
slideoutMenu.animate({
left: -slideoutMenuWidth
}, 250);    
}
});
});
```

css:

```
.slideout-menu {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: -250px;
width: 250px;
height: 100%;
background: #333;
z-index: 100;
}
.slideout-menu h3 {
position: relative;
padding: 12px 10px;
color: #fff;
font-size: 1.2em;
font-weight: 400;
border-bottom: 4px solid #222;
}
.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle {
position: absolute;
top: 12px;
right: 10px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 6px 9px 5px;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 1;
background: #222;
color: #999;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: top;
}
.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle:hover {
color: #fff;
}
.slideout-menu ul {
list-style: none;
font-weight: 300;
border-top: 1px solid #151515;
border-bottom: 1px solid #454545;
}
.slideout-menu ul li {
border-top: 1px solid #454545;
border-bottom: 1px solid #151515;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a {
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: 10px;
color: #999;
text-decoration: none;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a:hover {
background: #000;
color: #fff;
}
.slideout-menu ul li a i {
position: absolute;
top: 15px;
right: 10px;
opacity: .5;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slideout-menu">
<h3>Menu <a href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">×</a></h3>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Item <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<button class="slideout-menu-toggle">Toggle</button>
```

[jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/3k60L2wm/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help and time guys !

Here is how i finaly did it :

$(document).ready
(
    function()
    {
        $( "#menu" ).click
        (
                function()
            {
                $( "#nav1" ).animate
                (
                    {
                        width: "toggle",
                    }, 
                    {
                        duration: 1200,
                        specialEasing: {width: "easeInOutCubic",},
                        complete: function() 
                        {
                            /*$( this ).after( "Animation complete." );*/
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    }
);